# Character values being represented as inf

Tags: sql, r

I have a SQL SERVER database full of part numbers that are alphanumeric, such as 19E378. When I query these values using the sqlQuery() function of the RODBC package, R immediately recognizes this value as Inf. I assume it is considering scientific notation and thinks that 19E378 means 19 * 10 to the 378th power (corrected).

I have tried casting and converting the values in the SQL query to varchar to no avail. I tried as.character() around the entire query but simply got "Inf" as a string.

```
  library(RODBC)
  myConn <- odbcConnect('ServerName')
sqlQuery(myConn, "SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 Sku, ProdUrl FROM dbo.GSR_Aux_Source WHERE Sku = '19E378')
```

How can I get R to display the value as a string, instead of trying to interpret it at as a number?

Comment: Are these columns coming in as factors? Try `options(stringAsFactors = FALSE)`. This argument can also be used in the `sqlQuery` function. Alternatively, have whoever runs your SQL Server to convert these columns to character.

Comment: Doing more research, try using the `as.is` argument in the `sqlQuery` function.

Comment: The scientific notation `19E378` is the representation of the number `19*10^378` (not for 19 to the 378th power)

Comment: @giraffehere The data is in the database as varchar(255). I found a workaround by doing `'A'+Sku as Sku` and then using a regular expression to remove the A. I'm not happy with that solution, but it's at least a way to get the process running again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround by doing `'A'+Sku as Sku` and then using a regular expression to remove the A, this forces R to store the data as a character string before converting to "Inf" value.